# Oauth client disabled after enabling API access

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-cloud-storage

I've been using a service account to access the google cloud datastore API without issue, but after enabling the cloud storage API in the developer console and changing the scopes of the project appropriately, I am getting a "The OAuth client is disabled" error.

If I remove the cloud storage scope from the request, I can continue to use the service account without issue.

Do I need to regenerate the private key associated with the service account after enabling a new API?

Comment: I Agree with your answer try and regenerate the key, or just add a new one then you wont loose the old one that does work.

Comment: Thanks -- I would have already tried that but I only had edit access to the cloud console. After requesting owner access and creating a new service account I seem to have fixed the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I requested (and was granted) owner access to the repository which allowed me to create a new service account. After changing the request to use the new service account I can now authenticate with the expanded scopes.